# How To Use a Simple Datastore Variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have successfully run the guestbook tutorial in GAE but I am having a hard time understanding how to read and write to the Datastore.  In my programming experience. int x = 5  etc.  In the Guestbook tutorial, EVERYTHING is named `guestbook_name`.  The variables, the values, the Datastore keys, all named `guestbook_name` or `default_guestbook_name`.  I can't sort it out. It makes a new programmer's brain hurt!  I am sure the answer is right there in the basic tutorial but every other word is `guestbook_name`
How can I assign a value of 5 to a datastore object then make that value += 1 every time a certain URL is requested?  An example of this (in Python) would help me understand how to store and manipulate data.

Answer (score 2):

Guestbook tutorial has been a complex one to understand for many users. I suggest you to go through this video tutorial on datastore. Even though this tutorial is in java (not python as requested), It will help you to understand the concept of datastore better than Guestbook tutorial

[GAE Datastore tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_P1wcF_XBlE)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to change the values of the properties of an Entity "manually" from the `Datastore viewer`, "assigning a value of 5 to a datastore object" (which in this case means a property, for instance `Number_of_Trips` a `Car` Entity has taken in a car management app) will have to be done on the client side through URL requests. That said, there are a couple of example tutorials such as [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngine/article.html) and the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) You really need to be patient though.

Answer (score 0):

Guestbook tutorial is a good start, but you cannot learn a new language/platform from a simple application. I suggest that you read the documentation on how to use App Engine Datastore:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

It provides many useful examples and code samples.